# How can I get archives for specific category without category_base in the url?

Tags: archives, categories

I'm using this code to get archives for a specific category:

```
function extend_date_archives_add_rewrite_rules($wp_rewrite){
    $rules = array();
    $structures = array(
        $wp_rewrite->get_category_permastruct() . $wp_rewrite->get_date_permastruct(),
        $wp_rewrite->get_category_permastruct() . $wp_rewrite->get_month_permastruct(),
        $wp_rewrite->get_category_permastruct() . $wp_rewrite->get_year_permastruct(),
    );
    foreach( $structures as $s ){
        $rules += $wp_rewrite->generate_rewrite_rules($s);
    }
    $wp_rewrite->rules = $rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}
add_action('generate_rewrite_rules', 'extend_date_archives_add_rewrite_rules');
```

It works fine and I get an URL like:
example.com/category_base/category_name/date/YYYY/MM

The problem is that I would like to have an URL without the category_base: example.com/category_name/date/YYYY/MM

If I use a plugin to delete de "category_base" (like [WP no category base](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-no-category-base/)) or simply I use "str_replace" to delete the "category_base", I get a 404 error page in all pages and single pages.

What can I do?

Thanks.

**Added notes:**

If I use:

```
function extend_date_archives_flush_rewrite_rules(){
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}
add_action('init', 'extend_date_archives_flush_rewrite_rules');
function extend_date_archives_add_rewrite_rules($wp_rewrite){
    $rules = array();
    $structures = array(
        $wp_rewrite->get_category_permastruct() . $wp_rewrite->get_date_permastruct(),
        $wp_rewrite->get_category_permastruct() . $wp_rewrite->get_month_permastruct(),
        $wp_rewrite->get_category_permastruct() . $wp_rewrite->get_year_permastruct(),
    );
    foreach( $structures as $s ){
        $rules += $wp_rewrite->generate_rewrite_rules($s);
    }
    $wp_rewrite->rules = $rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}
add_action('generate_rewrite_rules', 'extend_date_archives_add_rewrite_rules');
```

example.com/category_name/YYYY  works fine, but single and pages go to 404 page. But If I only use:

```
function extend_date_archives_add_rewrite_rules($wp_rewrite){
        $rules = array();
        $structures = array(
            $wp_rewrite->get_category_permastruct() . $wp_rewrite->get_date_permastruct(),
            $wp_rewrite->get_category_permastruct() . $wp_rewrite->get_month_permastruct(),
            $wp_rewrite->get_category_permastruct() . $wp_rewrite->get_year_permastruct(),
        );
        foreach( $structures as $s ){
            $rules += $wp_rewrite->generate_rewrite_rules($s);
        }
        $wp_rewrite->rules = $rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
    }
    add_action('generate_rewrite_rules', 'extend_date_archives_add_rewrite_rules');
```

Then all single and pages work fine, but example.com/category_name/YYYY goes to 404.
Any idea? I refresh permalinks, and I continue with the problem :(

Comment: If you use the plugin alone the categories, singles, pages etc goes 404? If so there is something wrong in .htaccess or somewhere  else.
About URLs, iif a page and category has the same URL the category will display, but you can't reach the page anymore, (there's no any system notice on creating content with same URLs so far :p )

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I would like to get this URL: example.com/category_name/date/YYYY/MM

Comment: have a look at this plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-no-category-base/

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** Tried and works ok **only without** the [WP no category base](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-no-category-base/) plugin, this is, you have to cope with the *category* though you can change it freely in Permalink settings.

For a full URL in single posts, set the category structure in **Settings > Permalinks**, then in *Category Base* enter `/%category%/%postname%/` (image below).

[image: Custom Structure must be <code>/%category%/%postname%/</code>]

The function I teste is:

```
function extend_date_archives_flush_rewrite_rules(){
   global $wp_rewrite;
   $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}
add_action('init', 'extend_date_archives_flush_rewrite_rules');

function extend_date_archives_add_rewrite_rules($wp_rewrite){
$rules = array();
$structures = array(
    $wp_rewrite->get_category_permastruct() . $wp_rewrite->get_date_permastruct(),
    $wp_rewrite->get_category_permastruct() . $wp_rewrite->get_month_permastruct(),
    $wp_rewrite->get_category_permastruct() . $wp_rewrite->get_year_permastruct(),
);
foreach( $structures as $s ){
    $rules += $wp_rewrite->generate_rewrite_rules($s);
}
$wp_rewrite->rules = $rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}

add_action('generate_rewrite_rules','extend_date_archives_add_rewrite_rules');
```

Then You can access year `category/categoryname/2012/02`, month  `category/categoryname/2012/02` and day `site.com/category/the-categoryname/2012/02/25`.

I think you can try merge the plugin rewrite with this function because two rewrites seems to cause some conflict.

Comment: But have you tried it with or without my function?

Comment: With the function, I think there is no way to do without it.

Comment: I continue with problems. Read my last added notes.

Comment: Hi, sorry I overlooked the single access :( I'm not sure but two rewrite rules at same time (plugin and function) seems to cause a conflict. Is quite a hack to remove the category anyway, there's never been an intend from WP devs in removing it as far as I know :(